# Wordpress crashes Internal Redirect

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirection

I am trying to find the issue why my Wordpress installation makes a 10 times redirection and crashes the session. The hint that I am getting from the Apache logs is:

```
[perdir /usr/www/users/server/server.org/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /usr/www/users/server/server.org/index.php
 [rewrite:trace2] [pid 79207:tid 140188445558528] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client xxxx:46452] 185.93.229.14 - - [server.org/sid#7f805e2bda80][rid#7f805eabd0a0/initial] [perdir /usr/www/users/server/server.org/] trying to replace prefix /usr/www/users/server/server.org/ with /
 [rewrite:trace5] [pid 79207:tid 140188445558528] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client xxxx:46452] 185.93.229.14 - - [server.org/sid#7f805e2bda80][rid#7f805eabd0a0/initial] strip matching prefix: /usr/www/users/server/server.org/index.php -> index.php
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 79207:tid 140188445558528] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client xxxx46452] 185.93.229.14 - - [rid#7f805eabd0a0/initial] add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 79207:tid 140188445558528] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client xxxx:46452] 185.93.229.14 - - [server.org/sid#7f805e2bda80][rid#7f805eabd0a0/initial] [perdir /usr/www/users/server/server.org/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

From what I am getting server.org is redirecting to /index.php and it creates a loop, but I don't see how that's happening. Any ideas on how to detect it?

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# SSL and WWW
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# No SSL and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# No SSL and no WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(de|en|es|fr|ru)/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: what is the business related question or issue in here?

Comment: @djdomi I mentioned it in the post. I would like to know how to find what is causing the internal redirection to itself, since after 10 times the session is cancelled.

Comment: is this your private blog?

Comment: @djdomi it is not, it is a multisite installation.

Comment: Try replacing the substitution string `$1` with `-` (a single hyphen) in the 2nd and 3rd last rules (the only two rules that contain this substitution string).

Comment: and what is the business relationship in here?

Comment: Where exactly are these 10 internal redirections appearing in the error log (culminating in the "Limit reached..." error)? The log extract you've shown is a "normal" (and expected) "internal redirect". Are you suggesting that this is repeated 10 times? _Aside:_ Your first 3 rules (that canonicalise the request) are ridiculously verbose. You only need 1 rule here. However, you are inconsistently using both `HTTPS` and `ENV:HTTPS`. My guess is that you are behind a proxy and the use of `HTTPS` is entirely superfluous.

Comment: @MrWhite you think I should delete the HTTPS rules? I am behind a firewall.